# How do I remove the seasonality of a time series?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I want to know which is the procedure to remove the seasonality (anual cycle, monthly cycle, daily cycle) of a time serie. I plotted the Autocorrelogram of my time series and I extracted from there the seasonality (in my case, anual cycle), but I don't know how to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually time series is thought to be represented by following construction:

series = seasonal component + trend component + irregular component

One way to deseasonalize series is to extract trend and add irregular component back to the trend.

For example R has a function stl which can be used to form a three component matrix for time series. You can take trend and irregular component and form an deseasonalized series:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/stl.html

Actually since we observer only one time series and not these unobservable components, we need many assumptions when modeling these series.